# How to render mongoDB data without using any template engine

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How to render data from mongoDB without the usage of any template engine(ejs, handlebars)???
Is it possible to render data strait to html? How?
I've never done this before and have no idea how to do that.
Please, help me!!!
I'll be glad to any information or link where to read about it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing make a fetch() request from html and open an endpoint in your backend.

example:-

in backend

```
app.get("/products", async (req, res) => {
  const products = await getProductsFromMongodb();

  res.status(200).json(products);
});
```

in html

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>products lists here...</li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    async function fetchProducts() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/products");

        if (response.ok) {
          const products = await response.json();
          // show products name,tags ,description,etc...  in  lists of card by looping products
        } else {
          // show user friendly error inside to screen
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // show user friendly error inside to screen
      }
    }

    window.onload = () => {
      fetchProducts();
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. It really helped me out)